# How to SELECT with a LIMIT while needing multiple rows with a same column value?

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

I have the following table as an example.

```
id uid car 
1  3   BMW
2  3   AUDI
3  3   JEEP
4  5   MERC
5  6   BMW
6  6   FIAT
```

Now, I would like to get all cars but for only 2 users but don't know how many cars they have. When they all would have had only one car, I could just do a `LIMIT 3` but how can I do this to get all the cars, but only for 2 users?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish??

Comment: @KamranAli What I'm after is to get a list of users (with jQuery) that at first, shows only one car for each user. If you click on the user, you get to see all his cars. I can do this with multiple queries, but would rather have this all in one.

(PS, the real application is a bit to complicated to explain, so I use the cars as an example)

Comment: @ajreal how would that work? I never used GROUP_CONCAT before.

Comment: I think this can be done on the front end rather on the SQL side, you can simply fetch all the rows and than show/hide them using jquery on the front end.

Comment: True, but I like to show in the first row how many cars someone has (like: See all his 3 cars). So I will need that data upfront. Could this be done in one SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If the 2 users are unknown you can use MySQL GROUP_CONCAT

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT uid, GROUP_CONCAT(car) as cars FROM tablename GROUP BY uid ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 0,2");
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $userid = $get['uid'];
  $result = explode(",", $get['cars']);
  echo '<h2>User #' . $userid . ' owns the following cars:</h2>' . "\n";
  echo '<ul>' . "\n";
  foreach ($result as $car) {
    echo '  <li>' . $car . '</li>' . "\n";
  }
  echo '</ul>' . "\n";
}
```

*Note: Don't forget to change the tablename in the SELECT query*

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a solution because I don't know the users on forhand.

Comment: @Glooh - Ok! Just updated my answer. Should be exactly what you're looking for :)

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need! I tested it and can do some extra stuff on the frontend, but at least I have one query now. Thanks!!